# How to measure throughput of MQ

Tags: performance, jms, performance-testing, ibm-mq

I want to do performance test for queues built using MQ. The benchmark I am using for this testing is "rate of incoming messages" and "time to process messages or rate of processing messages". I am trying to figure rate of incoming messages.

Can someone please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: You may want to start by looking at the performance reports posted here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007150#1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ih03 MQ supportpac.
Its home page can be found [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24000637). Documentation is published [here](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/ih03.pdf).
Example use case of its usage is [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ibm-integration-bus-mapping-options-mostafa-emam).